# Combining AND and OR in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

i wrote this code to combine AND and OR but it does not work and it comes no error just didnt bring any result . I have values but they didnt come up .

```
        =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
                    ARRAYFORMULA(
                                IFERROR(
                                    INDEX(Lista!$A$2:$A$160;SMALL(
                                    IF(
                                        OR(
                                            AND(Lista!$H$2:$H$160="M";Lista!$D$2:$D$160="A");
                                            AND(Lista!$H$2:$H$160="M";Lista!$D$2:$D$160="C"));
                                        ROW(Lista!$H$2:$H$160)-ROW(Lista!$H$1));ROW(1:1)));"")); 1; 1)
```

This is working code but its not combinned .

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
        ARRAYFORMULA(
             IFERROR(INDEX(
                  Lista!$A$2:$A$159;SMALL(


  IF(Lista!$H$2:$H$159="R";IF(Lista!$D$2:$D$159="A";ROW(Lista!$H$2:$H$159)-ROW(Lista!$H$1)));ROW(12:12)));"")); 1; 1)
```

Is there something wrong ?

EDIT: Lista is an other sheet TAB .

What i want is : if in cell H is equal to M and in cell D  is equal to A then print the corresponding name in A 
OR if in cell H is equal to M and in cell D is euqal to C then print the corresponding name in A.

Comment: Don't tag with Excel if you don't use Excel. Google Sheets and Excel are **NOT** the same. Removing Excel tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and want share it maybe someone find it helpful .

```
 =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDEX(Lista!$A$2:$A$160;SMALL(
            IF(
            Lista!$H$2:$H$160="XX";
                    IF(Lista!$D$2:$D$160="A";ROW(Lista!$H$2:$H$160)-ROW(Lista!$H$1) ; 
                                    IF(Lista!$D$2:$D$160="C";ROW(Lista!$H$2:$H$160)-ROW(Lista!$H$1) ; )
            )
            );ROW(1:1)));"")); 1; 1)
```